# Suggest a new template file for a page node view

Tags: theming

I have a site which has two main views, a men's blog and a women's blog, both with their own content types, mens-blog-post and womens-blog-post. The problem I am facing is that they share the same page--node.tpl file (node page view, default file:page.tpl not node.tpl), but need to have different content (e.g. other relevant views in the sidebar region). I need to suggest two new template files called page--node--mens-blog-post.tpl.php and page--node—womens-blog-post.tpl.php based on content type.

Here is my attempt:

```
function force_preprocess_page(&$vars){
 if ($vars['content']->type == 'mens-blog-post') {
  array_unshift($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__mens_blog_post');
 } 
 if ($vars['content']->type == 'womens-blog-post'){
  array_unshift($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__womens_blog_post');
 } 
}
```

Can anyone help me clean this up and make it work? I am looking for any solution that works so I am open to other ideas.

Comment: Which errors do you get, or in which way isn't the code you wrote working? (You wrote, "help me clean this up and make it work.")

Comment: I'm not getting any errors the code just doesn't suggest the tpl file I need. I just assumed someone who knows this stuff well could take one look at it and see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using context (http://drupal.org/project/context) to swap out the content based on the content type. Big thanks to gilzero on my other post... sorry for the mess won't happen again.

Answer (score 7):

To use a different template file for the node being shown, you need to add a new suggestion in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` (Drupal 7), or `$variables['template_files']` (Drupal 6). In both the cases, the variable is an array.

In a module, the hook to implement is `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```
function force_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
    if ($variables['node']->type == 'mens-blog-post') {
      array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__mens_blog_post');
    }
    elseif ($variables['node']->type == 'womens-blog-post') {
      array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'page__node__mens_blog_post');
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a module called force.module, then your code is correct. The same code can be used for a theme whose short name is force; in this case, in its template.php file you add a `force_preprocess_page()` function.
In Drupal 6, your theme needs to also have the default template file (page.tpl.php), or the custom template is not going to be picked up. I didn't check if this is still valid in Drupal 7. (The only time I created a theme that was using a custom template file was in Drupal 6.)

I would rather check the variable `$variables['node']` is not empty, as `hook_preprocess_page()` is called for every page served from Drupal, including the ones not associated with any node.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Panels instead of a suggestion.

1. Active the "node view" page
2. Create two variants, with

   1. One selection rule for "mens-blog-post"
   2. Another selection rule "womens-blog-post"
3. Add "Node content" to a region.

Done.

Relevant video tutorials here: http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager first four videos should get you started :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it partially worked. My first problem is the panel is still using the same page--node.tpl so nothing has changed really just more complicated, secondly the custom breadcrumb trail no longer works, and thirdly I am getting a ton of errors about memory... any idea what I need to do to clean this up? You made it sound so easy...

Comment: Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in _drupal_bootstrap_full() (line 4909 of /Users/Ken/Sites/fource7/includes/common.inc).
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in drupal_load() (line 1114 of /Users/Ken/Sites/fource7/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Comment: 1) Custom breadcrumb, is indeed a problem, but has a patch here: http://drupal.org/node/1251520. 2) If you have verified that the node.tpl.php really is in use, then the selection rules are not configured correctly. 3) I How much memory does PHP have?

Comment: Did you actually watch any of the videos? That memory warning looks APC related, and probably has nothing to do with PHP's memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p

Comment: I did. Maybe I need to go back over them. I found that the breadcrumbs don't work only when I specify to serve the body content. When I specify the node's full content the breadcrumbs do work. Any idea why that is? Can you explain?

Comment: I am dealing with the node_view system page. Using theme developer I did confirm that the page is using page--node.tpl. The selection rule is set to node: type specified to my custom content type. The content is served/filtered correctly so I do know it is working but the tpl file is the same as before...?

Comment: The memory error is very strange as I have allocated 128M to the system in the php.ini file. I will try the APC fix.Thanks

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like you've gotten it right so far, but you do need to have _two_ variants, one for each content type, or you won't have a (good) way of differentiating between them.

Comment: I just setup the second variant and it appears to be working. I removed the extra content through the content type so filtering the full node content is no longer a problem...breadcrumbs as well... but I am still using the same page--node.tpl file and getting the same suggestions which are not specific enough. I'm not sure what this has done for me...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2131/discussion-between-letharion-and-kenaesthetic)

Comment: Very long discussion, I need to learn to be much more precise in my answers. :) Sorry for being unclear initially. You can add content in completely different areas, have entirely different layouts, show different views, or more or less anything you want, differently on the two variants. I feel like I have wasted your time now, but this is how we handle, and differentiate _all_ node content at our company.

Comment: Thats ok. appreciate the effort. I am learning here so anything helps. Thanks Letharion